# Options for creating Java classes in Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

There are a few different ways to create Java classes in Clojure, so what are the tradeoffs when picking between [`gen-class`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/gen-class), [`proxy`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/proxy), and [`reify`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reify) in Clojure?  (are there other ways to create Java classes that I haven't listed?)

My basic understanding is that I have listed these constructs in decreasing order of power.

Answer (score 18):

Use `gen-class` when you want a named class or you want to add new methods to objects you create.  `gen-class` relies on AOT compilation.

When you want an anonymous, one-off implementation of a type you use `reify` or `proxy`.  They do not rely on AOT compilation. Here are their differences:

1. `reify` only supports protocols or interfaces, `proxy` also supports concrete superclasses.
2. `reify` uses true class methods, `proxy` uses external functions.
3. Because of #2, `reify` uses direct method lookup, while `proxy` uses a map for method lookup.
4. Because of #3, `reify` does not support dynamic swapping of methods, but `proxy` does.

`reify` will perform better than `proxy`, so you should always use `reify` when possible.  Only use `proxy` when `reify`'s constraints are too prohibitive.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to gen-class, proxy and reify, we have defrecord and deftype.  These latter two options should be your first choices for the creation of named java classes (and in the case of defrecord, your first choice for any kind of struct with named components.)

The [datatypes page on clojure.org](http://clojure.org/datatypes) is a good reference on this topic.  Defrecord, deftype and reify are newer than gen-class and proxy, having been introduced in version 1.2 (I think -- possibly 1.1).  Defrecord and deftype both create classes that conform to interfaces, but do not allow for inheritance.  If you need inheritance, gen-class (and proxy for anonymous classes) is still your only option.

Defrecord and deftype differ in what you are given for free.  Defrecord automatically creates a class which conforms to IPersistentMap and ISeq.  Deftype, on the other hand, gives you more control over your class, even allowing for mutable fields (not allowed in defrecord).  In general, deftype is intended for low-level implementation of data structures, whereas defrecord is intended for most day-to-day use.